# Список локальных IP-адресов

Tags: c++, winapi, сеть, сокет, posix

Можно ли получить все доступные IP-адреса хоста, не используя для этого его имя?
Гугление привело к мысли, что под `ОС Windows` это придется делать с помощью функций `GetAdaptersInfo\GetAdaptersAddresses`, а под никсами - `getifaddrs()`, которую, в свою очередь, нельзя считать портабельной. Не существует какого-то более хитрого способа узнать поддерживается ли стеком TCP/IP хоста протокол IPv4 и IPv6 (да, изначально я хотел получить эти адреса для того, чтобы определить поддержку вышеуказанных протоколов)?

UPD0: Для ОС Windows (вдруг кому-то пригодится):

```
#define WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE 15000
#define MAX_TRIES 3
#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define   FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

bool existLocalInterfaceSupportedSelectedNetFamily(int netFamily)
{
    bool bLookupResult = false;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAdapterAddrs = NULL;

    DWORD dwIterationResult = 0x00;
    ULONG ulIterationsCnt = 0x00;
    ULONG ulBufLength = WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE;

    do
    {
        pAdapterAddrs = (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)MALLOC(WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE);
        dwIterationResult = GetAdaptersAddresses(netFamily
            , GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX
            , NULL
            , pAdapterAddrs
            , &ulBufLength);

        if (dwIterationResult == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
        {
            FREE(pAdapterAddrs);
            pAdapterAddrs = NULL;
        }
        else
            break;

        ++ulIterationsCnt;
    } 
    while (dwIterationResult == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW && ulIterationsCnt < MAX_TRIES);

    if (dwIterationResult == NO_ERROR)
    {
        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurAdapterAddrs = NULL;
        for (pCurAdapterAddrs = pAdapterAddrs; pCurAdapterAddrs; pCurAdapterAddrs = pCurAdapterAddrs->Next)
            if ( pCurAdapterAddrs->IfType != IF_TYPE_SOFTWARE_LOOPBACK )
                bLookupResult |= (pCurAdapterAddrs->Flags
                    & ((netFamily == AF_INET) ? IP_ADAPTER_IPV4_ENABLED : IP_ADAPTER_IPV6_ENABLED) != 0x00);

    }

    if (pAdapterAddrs)
        FREE(pAdapterAddrs);

    return bLookupResult;
}
```

Comment: getaddrinfo? А вообще строго переносимого способа нет, поэтому существует   такой сложный функционал в библиотеках Qt и пр. для абстрактного представления сетевых интерфейсов системы.

Comment: @Swift, писал об этом, но один товарищ с большой репутацией счел это излишней информацией в моем вопросе. Если Вам не сложно, загляните в историю, скажите, что думаете.

Comment: ну, протоколы транспортного и сетевого уровня абсолютно изолированы друг от друга, клиент ничего не узнает кроме того что ему удался connect() или нет. С UDP  и ЭТОГО нет,  одна сторона посылает пакеты, другая принимает.. молча. Вот если принимающая сторона не слушала на том адресе и  порте, тогда будет диагностика. А чтобы выдать информацию о допустимых протоколах на удаленном хосте, нужен отдельный протокол приложения, возможно по TCP..

Comment: Какая у вас проблема с приведённым кодом? Если он работает как ожидается, то опубликуйте своё решение как ответ.

Comment: @jfs, Swift - друзья, мне нужно определить поддержку IPv4/IPv6 на локальной машине. Приведенный код - версия для Windows, я же искал универсальную для Windows/Linux.

Comment: Чтобы получить список сетевых интерфейсов и соответствующие им адреса из заданных семейств, я успешно использовал [`netifaces` Питон модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) на Linux:`from netifaces import *; ips = [link['addr'] for interface in interfaces() for family in [AF_INET, AF_INET6] for link in ifaddresses(interface).get(family,())]`. Документация заявляет поддержку также  macOS и Windows. Можно [посмотреть как netifaces на C реализован](https://bitbucket.org/al45tair/netifaces/src/63175eb336b10b502cab4cc2f0d205b9b22e58d5/netifaces.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: @jfs, мне для работы нужно, все, чем там  могу пользоваться - это плюсы и системные вызовы. А вот за ссылку netifaces на C - огромное спасибо!